# Do dos pipes work with the cmd tool?

Tags: java, cmd, pipe

I have a piece of java code that I wish to run set up as follows:

```
cmd /c mysqldump db1 | mysql db2
```

Does anyone know of a reason that this might not work? I am manipulating some MyISAM
tables but am replacing the brute force copies with dump / reloads in anticipation of
moving the database engine over to InnoDB.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Pipes definitely work in Windows. `dir | clip`, for example.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem... my solution was to write everything in a script file and to run it.

```
FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter("test.bat");
fw1.write("mysqldump db1 | mysql db2");
fw1.flush();
fw1.close();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd /c test.bat" );
```

probably there are better solutions...!

Comment: Thanks...  I was experimenting with dumping to a "temp" file and then reloading.  The process is pretty slow as these are large tables (that is one reason we are looking into InnoDB)